# Xamarin Forms: Toolbar not showing in Jellybean 4.3

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms, added the below code for Toolbar, but it not showing on the right top (with 3 dots) and but I could see Menu when I use Menu hardware button on device.

Device running Android Jelly bean 4.3.

```
<ToolbarItem Text="QUICK LINKS"   Activated="OnToolBarClick"  Order="Secondary" Priority="0" />
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the `NavigationBar` showing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you create the instance of the page containing the toolbar, you use the NavigationPage class to wrap it, otherwise the toolbar will not be displayed.

For example, assume UpdateScoresPage is the page with the toolbar in, and we're calling this from the parent page.  If you omit `new NavigationPage(page)` the toolbar will not show.

```
UpdateScoresPage page = new UpdateScoresPage(Model, model);
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page));
```